# R Scale plot elements within PDF of set width and height

Tags: r, pdf, plot, ggplot2

Though R plots sent to a PDF can be rescaled at will in an illustration or page layout software, scientific journals often insist that the plots provided have specific dimensions.

Can the size of all plotting elements be scaled within a given PDF size directly in R?

```
require(ggplot2)

p <- qplot(data=iris,
           x=Petal.Width,
           y=Petal.Length,
           colour=Species)

pdf("./test_plot_default.pdf")
print(p)
graphics.off()
```

Produces adequate scaling of plot elements

[image: test plot with default pdf size]

However, changing PDF size elements does not cause the plot elements to scale.  With smaller PDFs, the plotting elements are overly enlarged compared to the plotting space.

```
pdf("./test_plot_dimentionsions required by journal.pdf", width=3, height=3)
print(p)
graphics.off()
```

[image]

Using @Rosen Matev suggestion:

```
update_geom_default("point", list(size=1))
theme_set(theme_grey(base_size=6))
pdf("./test_plot_dimentionsions required by journal.pdf", width=3, height=3)
print(p)
graphics.off()
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to continue using the `pdf()` function as it allows me to easily create a pdf document with many plots.

Comment: I don't understand the question. text, point, line sizes are measured in absolute (physical) units, specifically designed to make them independent of the device size (provided you don't rescale the image afterwards). Isn't that precisely what you want?

Comment: I understand the advantage of having all measurements in absolute units.  Is there a way to make the size of all elements scale with device size?  Or do I need to use external software to rescale the pdf after.

Comment: What I do, is a) measuring the space I had in the pdf and set the output size to this; then b) set the font size to the one required by the publisher; then c) tweak your plot so that the pdf that falls out of R fits into your article **unscaled**. I found this to be a very good approach.

Comment: @EtienneLow-Décarie I understand your point, you need scale your graphics the way which does not tweak the plot and still you would like to use direct pdf output. I have solved the same thing for myself the way I have answered. I do not have ggplot2 installed, but I belive it will work the same way. See my answer, I only had problems when my pdf size was too small (under 3.5 inches). Which could be the case of multicolumn paper, in that case I was forced to play more with pdf settings or plot area not to waste space.

Comment: `update_geom_default()` is missing an `s`: `update_geom_defaults()`

Answer (score 11):

Consider using **width**, **height** and **pointsize** in pdf() function.

If you like to stick with using pdf() instead of other ways like using sweave, then you would better use pdf function with more arguments, like bellow (I do not have ggplot2 installed, so simillar case is supplied).

```
# making scaled plot in pdf
# using paper=a4 just to see the efect

for (sc in c(0.5,0.75,1)) {
pdf(width=7*sc,height=7*sc,pointsize=12*sc,file=paste("scale",sc,".pdf",sep=""),paper="a4")
plot(sin((1:314)/100),main=paste("PDF sc",sc))
dev.off()  
}
```

It is quite usable, but works in some extent. Once the scale is too small, pdf will start to enforce linewidth, fontsize etc.

See the results in scale*.pdf created by example.

**And for ggplot2 ...**

```
sc <- c(0.5,0.75,1)
fi <- c("pic1.pdf","pic2.pdf","pic3.pdf")

require(ggplot2)
p <- qplot(data=iris,
x=Petal.Width,
y=Petal.Length,
colour=Species)

for (i in 1:3) {
pdf(width=7*sc[i],height=7*sc[i],pointsize=12*sc[i],file=fi[i])
print(p)
dev.off()  
}
```

Latex code to test the files how they look in one document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
     \includegraphics{pic1.pdf}
 \end{figure}

\begin{figure}
     \includegraphics{pic2.pdf}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{pic3.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is adjusting both pointsize and the size of the PDF.  Sadly, setting PDF size and adjusting pointsize to fit does not solve my issue as not all parameters produced by ggplot are scaled by pointsize.

Comment: Right, I have figured that also, it could the case of all "grid" based systems. Or is it ggplot only?

Answer (score 9):

Oddly enough, you can do this with `scale=` in `ggsave(...)`

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- qplot(data=iris, x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length, colour=Species)
ggsave("test.1.pdf",p)
ggsave("test.2.pdf",p, width=3, height=3, units="in", scale=3)
```

Try playing with the `scale` parameter and see what you get...

Comment: Though this does produce a plot that looks good, it has the same problems as with the pdf() above.  The command `ggsave("test.2.pdf",p, width=3, height=3, units="in", scale=3)` does not produce a 3"x3" pdf but rather a 9"x9" pdf.  It appears that the scale parameter overrides the width and height parameters. `ggsave("test.2.pdf",p, width=3, height=3)` creates a 3"x3" plot but that has the same problems as the one produce by `pdf()`.

Answer (score 6):

Journals insist on having specific plot dimensions in order to avoid scaling. If made, it can render the font size too small (or large) and inconsistent with the figure caption font size. That is why the plot elements (text, point size, etc.) by design have the same absolute size regardless of pdf size.

You can change the default font size and point size, for example, with:

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length, colour=Species)) +
  geom_point(size=1.5) +  # default is 2
  theme_grey(base_size=10)  # default is 12
ggsave("test.1.pdf", p)
```

The defaults can be changed globally, too:

```
update_geom_defaults("point", list(size=1.5))
theme_set(theme_grey(base_size=10))
```

Answer (score -1):

An option equally good or better than pdf is tiff. All journals I have come across like tiff.

```
tiff(filename="name.tiff", width=5, height=5, units="in",
     pointsize=8, compression="lzw", bg="white", res=600,
     restoreConsole=TRUE)
qplot(data=iris, x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length, colour=Species)
dev.off()
```

If you are on linux, drop `restoreConsole=TRUE`, seems only windows likes that.

Comment: Vector graphics always print better than raster graphics. Even if the resolution of the picture equals the resolution of the printer, there must only be the slightest scaling anywhere during the process and  things break.