# Scale ggplot window and geom elements without altering text or export image size

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, fonts, scale

I regularly produce `ggplot()` graphics and have struggled to come across a way to scale the plot window without affecting other elements such as titles, axis labels, axes text, legends, etc. I typically use `ggsave()` and have pulled from [here](http://stat545.com/block017_write-figure-to-file.html) a bit but due to scaling and resizing issues they never get standardized. I'm trying to get better at streamlining everything but have come to a roadblock. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484999/r-scale-plot-elements-within-pdf-of-set-width-and-height) is a similar question asking how to do the same thing with `pdf()` though the central problem appears to be the same.

## Question

Is there any way to adjust the scaling of only the plot window and (*edit: non-text*) geom elements without adjusting text or image size?

## Example:

Here's some sample data I'm working with. Percent of jobs filled and offered by day of week:

```
dput(day_data)
structure(list(day = structure(c(2L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M", "R", "Sa", "Su", "T", "W"), class = "factor"), 
order = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), Status = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Jobs Filled", 
"Jobs Offered"), class = "factor"), total = c(13724496, 15298119, 
15293656, 16272599, 17652393, 16252141, 17590028, 17549470, 
18875899, 21441775), percent = c(17.5, 19.5, 19.5, 20.8, 
22.6, 17.7, 19.2, 19.1, 20.6, 23.4)), .Names = c("day", "order", 
"Status", "total", "percent"), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's some sample code to produce a graph. It doesn't look quite like my attached images but that's because I dropped unnecessary theme and other tidy-up elements to shoot for a minimally reproducible example.

```
ggplot(data=month_data, aes(x=reorder(month, order_sch), y=percent, fill=Status)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent, y=percent+0.2),
            position=position_dodge(width=1),
            family="serif") +
  labs(x="Day of Week", 
   y="Percent") +
  theme(text = element_text(size=12, family="serif"))
```

Now, here's the nitty gritty of the problem. When using `ggsave()`, we can specify a given height and width, and once we do that in combination with setting `element_text(size=12)` everything should be set. But, sometimes the plot doesn't look quiet the same. Attached are two examples, showing the difference in scaling. The first was done with `scale=1`, the default, and the second was done with `scale=4`, and extreme example. One might think `scale` could be used to adjust only the plot window and not other (text) elements, but actually all it does is override the `height` and `width` arguments and act as a multiplier. So if height/width/scale = 4/4/1 we get a 4"x4" image, but if height/width/scale = 4/4/4 we get a 16"x16" image.

```
ggsave(paste0(getwd(), "/example.jpg"), width=4, height=4, dpi=300)
```

[image]
[image]

So the question again: Is there any way to adjust the scaling of only the plot window and bar/line/etc elements without adjusting text or image size? Can it be done either within the original `ggplot()` call or within `ggsave()` or someother export function?**

Comment: Have you tried `rel` at all to work with [the relative size of elements](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/2.1.0/topics/rel)?

Comment: @aosmith I can't find any thorough documentation. How exactly does `rel()` work? What is it relative to? What does it mean to set `element_text(size=rel(12))`? How do I know what that mean in terms of font size? Does it work outside of `theme()`, for example, on my axis labels and `geom_text()`?

Comment: [This question with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663915/what-is-parent-element-of-ggplot2) addresses most of the questions in your comment.